# How to select always first TR in any DIV with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a site with different count of this DIV with different count of TABLES and I want to always delete the first TR of the first TABLE. With this code only the first DIV works. What's wrong with this jquery?

```
<div style=background:khaki;padding:8>
<table border=1 cellpadding=8>
<tr><td><table border=1 cellpadding=8>
<tr><td>text 1</td><td>text 2</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>
<tr><td>text 3</td></tr>
<tr><td><table border=1 cellpadding=8>
<tr><td>text 4</td><td>text 5</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
text 6
</div>
<br>
<div style=background:coral;padding:8>
<table border=1 cellpadding=8>
<tr><td><table border=1 cellpadding=8>
<tr><td>text 1</td><td>text 2</td></tr>
</table></td></tr>
<tr><td>text 3</td></tr>
<tr><td><table border=1 cellpadding=8>
<tr><td>text 4</td><td>text 5</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
text 6
</div>
```

$("div tr:eq(0)").css("background","black");

http://jsfiddle.net/tjZSm/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made a minor change to your fiddle, which should work:

`$("div").find('tr:first').css("background","black");`

This first selects all `div`s, then all the first `tr` in those `div`

Answer (score 0):

From the jquery :eq() documentation

```
 <script>
/* applies yellow background color to a single <li> */
$("ul.nav li:eq(1)").css( "backgroundColor", "#ff0" );

/* applies italics to text of the second <li> within each <ul class="nav"> */
$("ul.nav").each(function(index) {
  $(this).find("li:eq(1)").css( "fontStyle", "italic" );
});

/* applies red text color to descendants of <ul class="nav"> */
/* for each <li> that is the second child of its parent */
$("ul.nav li:nth-child(2)").css( "color", "red" );
</script>
```

You need to either provide an each function where you'll `find()` each tr:eq(0) or use the tr:first-child notation